# How is this question too localized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

My one of questions has been closed: [Why can't I see the +1 button on some apps in the Play Store app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31833/why-do-not-all-apps-get-1-button)
Reason: Too Localized

I am unable to understand why its too localized. How is it different from "I am unable to purchase an app" or "I am unable to download an app" type Play Store question? Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-opened it.  I don't think one person verifying that they can see the buttons is enough to say that no one else will be unable to see them, like you.  I can't think of any reason why this would be happening to you and only you, so I think it passes the "potentially useful to others" metric.

The nature of the question obviously changed due to the comments, however — it's some combination of your account/location/environment/app version/etc. and the particular apps rather than something about the particular apps that affects everyone.  I've edited it as such, please make sure to do such editing yourself when possible.  Secondly the question would benefit from extra information, such as:

- Your location and carrier
- Your device and Android version
- Your version of the Play Store
- A screenshot of the behavior